# Azure Logic Apps - Verify content in JSON file

Tags: json, azure, validation, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that runs as follows:

- Step 1 = Recurrence (the schedule for the logic app to run)
- Step 2 = HTTP (Performing a POST call on a custom API that returns a JSON file)
- Step 3 = Create Blob (which uploads said document from **Step 2** and uploads it to blob storage)

What I would like to do now is **add an extra step between Step 2 and Step 3**.  After making the HTTP POST call, I would like to verify the content inside the JSON file that gets returned.  If there is an error present in the JSON file, I want the Logic App to stop there.

Is there a particular step that I can use in Azure's Logic App to verify the data and have that step decide if it should continue on or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, you can refer to my logic app below:

**1.** I initialize a variable named "**resultFromHTTP**" to simulate the json from your HTTP request(step 2). And I delete some character, so the "**resultFromHTTP**" is not a valid json format.

[image]

**2.** Then I initialize another variable and use the expression `json(variables('resultFromHTTP'))` in its value.

[image]

**3.** Run the logic app, it will fail and show error message like below screenshot. If the json is in valid format, it will run success.

[image]

===============================**Update**==============================

For your latest question, if the result json from HTTP request is not in valid json format and not a very long string, you can do it like this:

[image]

The `contains(...` expression is `contains(variables('resultFromHTTP'), 'Data Not Found')`. Then you can do what you want under "if true" or "if false".

If the result json from HTTP request is in valid json format, you can use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse it and get the specified field and then judge if it equals to "Data Not Found".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you were trying to do. Is there a way to pick a particular string out of the JSON file and have it fail if the specified text is present?  For example, if it found the words 'Data Not Found' then it would fail.

Comment: Hi @Tscott please refer to the "Update" of my answer. If still have any problem, please le t me know.

Comment: Hi @Tscott May I know if you problem was solved ? If the solution works, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance~